# how can we connect existing postgres database with new next application using prisma

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, next.js, prisma

I have a database with a lot of data.... that was being handled by Dot Net core framework.
Now i want a small admin panel using nextjs i want to connect that database with my new next js application using Prisma.
But without schema Prisma won't work.
anyone please explain what is the best way to do it.

I have tried db. pull it creates schema but when i access that schema with Prisma client. it shows error.

`const user = await prisma.post.findFirst({ where: { name: "ali" } });`

**your text**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eqLw.png)

Comment: put in the correct database credentials via https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/reference/connection-urls

Comment: database successfully connected...
my question is i have new next application setup...postgres db already there with data.
how can i query that data using prisma without schema ?

Comment: database already setup and have data in it. with dot net schema.

Comment: you can not, prisma needs a schema to know what it can query

Comment: is there anyother solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using **queryRaw** method to execute raw SQL queries against your PostgreSQL database. In your case, hope it'll work.

```js
const prisma = require('./prisma/client');

async function fetchData() {
  try {
    const result = await prisma.$queryRaw`SELECT * FROM your_table_name`;
    console.log(result);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
  } finally {
    await prisma.$disconnect();
  }
}

fetchData();
```

Or you can also consider creating prisma schema from your existing database using these commands

- **npx prisma introspect**
- **npx prisma generate**

Comment: Why do you use snippet?

Comment: Thanks for catching that mistake; I've fixed it now.

Comment: when i try to run raw query, it pull data from wrong database or tables.
how to specify a database into raw query ?

Answer (score 0):

***"when i try to run raw query, it pull data from wrong database or tables. how to specify a database into raw query?"***

You need to specify your **database connection URL** while creating a Prisma client.

import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

```
const prisma = new PrismaClient({
  datasources: {
    db: {
      url: 'your_database_connection_url_here', // Update with your actual connection URL
    },
  },
});

export default prisma;
```

Comment: raw queries are enable us to get post data into tables without schema ?

Comment: Raw queries let you insert data into tables without strict schema rules, but it's important to validate data for consistency. The recommended approach is to use a well-defined schema.